# Anyone Else Having Trouble Registering Ghostdriver with Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid

I know that there is documentation on the ghostdriver wiki on how to attach it to a selenium grid. For those that don't know you can find it [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#register-ghostdriver-with-a-selenium-grid-hub)

I've compiled the special phantomjs twice, tried to attach it to selenium servers local, and remote using both Selenium versions 2.24 and 2.25 to no avail. It starts up Ghostdriver locally just like you expect, but there's certainly no registering going on.

I tried both ip/localhost:4444 and ip/localhost:4444/grid/register with no results. I also thought perhaps it just didn't show up on the grid console and tried to run tests against it anyway, which failed stating there was nothing populating the grid.

I've tried this on both CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 12.04 with no luck.

I'm out of ideas. Has anyone else had problems like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and fixed it with using the lastest version of selenium-grid.

The good website: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 (this is no longer http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/).

Here the steps (version 2.31.0):

Download the selenium-server:

```
wget https://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
```

Launch selenium grid server:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub
```

In a new terminal, launch GhostDriver:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=5555 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
```

Check out available remote control on `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`.

You should see something like that:

```
listening on http://127.0.0.1:5555
test session time out after 300 sec.
Supports up to 1 concurrent tests from: 
phantomjs
```

I was testing this commands on CentOS 6.3, I hope it works for you!