# Can I run Selenium grid without browsers?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm aware that I can export Selenium to Junit for webdriver 4 and run the tests as an application (without the need for a browser)

I was looking to do some load testing with Selenium Grid and I do not know if this is also possible on that level i.e. running parallel instances of my Selenium test with the same node/hub architecture. I'm looking to scale to about 100,000 instances and I would appreciate any insight

Thanks a million!

Comment: The batch files I have here will help you accomplish this but the node1Config.json file would have to be modified to spawn only PhantomJS instances: https://github.com/djangofan/selenium-framework-concept1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should setup: `Selenium ghostdriver` (`selenium webdriver` with `phantom.js`) with `selenium grid`.

To set up, see:

- [Anyone Else Having Trouble Registering Ghostdriver with Selenium Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713913/anyone-else-having-trouble-registering-ghostdriver-with-selenium-grid)
- [Can't use RemoteWebDriver(Ghost,Phantom) via Selenium Grid2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517165/cant-use-remotewebdriverghost-phantom-via-selenium-grid2/15813181#15813181)

To see how to go for selenium webdriver + selenium grid, see:

- http://qtp-help.blogspot.de/2011/09/selenium-grid-with-webdriver.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe just using HtmlUnit driver can help you in this case, without the hub/node architecture, and no browsers.

Also maybe you can think of a solution using this : 
[effective scalable testing lab](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/build-effective-web-ui-testing-lab/)

[disclosure : i work for Ravello]

Comment: well, my experience with HtmlUnit driver is that in case page is not static, it's not usable